# What is a "variable" in C++?

Tags: c++, variables

I was looking through C++17 for the formal definition of what the term "variable" means and all could find was in section 6:

> A variable is introduced by the declaration of a reference other than a non-static data member or of an object. The variable’s name, if any, denotes the reference or object.

Since I was expecting something more along the lines of "A variable is...", I searched the Internet and found several different definitions.  The one that seemed to most closely fit what the standard appears to be saying was something like,

> "A variable is an object paired with an identifier (if any)."

If that is a correct rewording and if the declaration int x; is assumed, it seems that it would be technically incorrect (but maybe colloquially correct) to simply state that "x is a variable".

Are my interpretations/conclusions correct?  When writing documentation for beginning programmers I typically get hung up on the semantics of such things because, while I want my documents to be correct, I don't want to confuse beginners with materials that read like the standards :-)

Comment: I just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59517136/827263) to the duplicate question. Summary: The C++ standard's definition of variable isn't really a definition. (The question is not what "variable" means in mathematics, or even in programming in general. It's how the C++ standard defines it.)