# How can I prevent storing an intrusive_ptr-based class in other smart pointers

Tags: c++, boost, smart-pointers

At work we have a base class, let's call it IntrusiveBase, that acts something like a mixin to allow a class to be stored in a boost:intrusive_ptr. That is, it provides its subclasses with a ref count and defines intrusive_ptr_add_ref and intrusive_ptr_release overloads. The problem is that it is too easy for someone to forget that a particular subclass inherits from IntrusiveBase, and they then store it in some other smart pointer like a scoped_ptr or shared_ptr. That doesn't work because, for example, the scoped_ptr will delete the object when it goes out of scope no matter what the ref count happens to be. We have an assertion in ~IntrusiveBase that the ref count is one, but this is not foolproof because oftentimes there will end up only being the original instance by the time the scoped_ptr goes out of scope. This leaves an insidious failure waiting to happen those few times that the ref count is *not* one.

Is there any way that I can cause a compile-time failure if someone accidentally does this? Even if I have to do something repetitively for each of the major smart pointer classes, it would be worth it.

Comment: You should probably allow use of scoped_ptr -- anyone using scoped_ptr probably understands that that single block of code should own that instance of the class.

Comment: `intrusive_ptr` as a base class is always annoying. Think about the dreaded diamond inheritance hierarchy... That's why `unique_ptr`, `scoped_ptr` and `shared_ptr` are so popular.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Even if I have to do something repetitively for each of the major smart pointer classes, it would be worth it.

In that case, you can specialize them on your InstrusiveBase inheriting types.

```
  namespace boost
  {
    template<>
    class scoped_ptr<InstrusiveBaseSubclass> { }; // scoped_ptr<InstrusiveBaseSubClass> p(new InstrusiveBaseSubClass) won't compile, neither will p->, p.get() etc.

  }
```

This is annoying but it's macro-able, e..g:

```
 class A : InstrusiveBase
 { 
     ...
 }
 NO_SCOPED_PTR(A)
 NO_SHARED_PTR(A)
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to overload new and delete for those classes and make delete private or protected. instrusive_ptr_release could then be made a friend function or similar technique used to actually invoke delete when the ref count dropped to zero.

Comment: So, I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I ran into this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820069/public-operator-new-private-operator-delete-getting-c2248-can-not-access-priva